# Unable to navigate html source after login pop up

Tags: selenium

I am running selenium to navigate a site (login) & scrape data. However I think selenium seems to only be able to navigate the HTML doc and not the DOM, unless I am not understanding how the page is rendered. Specifically, when I open *moodys.com*
, I can find the login button. However when the login pop up appears, there is a disconnect between the source code and the element inspection i.e. I can see the html code under element inspection however it does not appear in the source code, so I cannot select the login box when I would like to enter my credentials.

this code works fine:

```
capabilities = { 'chromeOptions':  { 'useAutomationExtension': False}}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities = capabilities)
driver.get("https://www.moodys.com")

driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".nav-bottom-item-container.login-item").click()
```

However I cannot then find a way to enter my credentials, as stated. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following code works for me (with an error for invalid credentials of course):

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.login-name:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(1)").send_keys("dummy")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.login-name:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(1)").send_keys("pwd")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.neptune_button_1mg2h:nth-child(2)").click()
```

Comment: Jens thats amazing, thank you. Could you elaborate on the syntax you used and why the disconnect between the html source and the DOM? Thanks again